# Create a daily timeline calendar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, calendar

I’m looking for advice on how to approach building a SwiftUI daily calendar list as I'm struggling to think how to even approach this.

This is the type of list I’m trying to create: [image](https://i.postimg.cc/GByjXgkk/Screenshot-2023-05-08-at-1-56-43-pm.png)

I can create the VStack to loop over the hours in the day vertically and then the dividing lines too - which looks like the Apple Calendar app view: [blank list](https://i.postimg.cc/K1VNrhgG/Screenshot-2023-05-08-at-1-50-41-pm.png)

What I can’t figure out is how to align the calendar entries to the time, and then spanning it over multiple hours if it is long event.

I receive the event data from MSGraph with a startDate and endDate.

I don't require dragging ability of the events, only displaying them in the time slots.

My aim is to build it all myself, though I know there are probably packages that could help. It's just a small part of the app that I didn't want to overload with calendar functionalities when I wanted to have just a viewer.

This is where I am at, but dont know how to add the events into the list:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
 var body: some View {
  ScrollView {
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    ForEach(8..<17) { index in
      Text("\(index)")
      Divider()
       .offset(y: -22)
       .padding(.leading, 30)
      Spacer()
     }
    }
   }
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
   .padding()
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your deployment target? If you are targeting at least iOS 16, you can use the [`Layout` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout), which is probably the most straightforward and powerful solution.

Comment: @robmayoff iOS15+ is the target in SwiftUI. targeting some older iPads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the single events over the hours grid as overlay or in an ZStack. You have to calculate an offset based on start date.

Here would be a sample implementation:

[image]

```
struct Event: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date
    var title: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let date: Date = dateFrom(9, 5, 2023)
    
    let events: [Event] = [
        Event(startDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,7,0), endDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,8,0), title: "Event 1"),
        Event(startDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,9,0), endDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,10,0), title: "Event 2"),
        Event(startDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,11,0), endDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,12,00), title: "Event 3"),
        Event(startDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,13,0), endDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,14,45), title: "Event 4"),
        Event(startDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,15,0), endDate: dateFrom(9,5,2023,15,45), title: "Event 5"),
    ]
    
    let hourHeight = 50.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            // Date headline
            HStack {
                Text(date.formatted(.dateTime.day().month()))
                    .bold()
                Text(date.formatted(.dateTime.year()))
            }
            .font(.title)
            Text(date.formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.wide)))
            
            ScrollView {
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(7..<19) { hour in
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(hour)")
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .frame(width: 20, alignment: .trailing)
                                Color.gray
                                    .frame(height: 1)
                            }
                            .frame(height: hourHeight)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(events) { event in
                        eventCell(event)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func eventCell(_ event: Event) -> some View {
        
        let duration = event.endDate.timeIntervalSince(event.startDate)
        let height = duration / 60 / 60 * hourHeight
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: event.startDate)
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: event.startDate)
        let offset = Double(hour-7) * (hourHeight)
//                      + Double(minute)/60 ) * hourHeight
        
        print(hour, minute, Double(hour-7) + Double(minute)/60 )

        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(event.startDate.formatted(.dateTime.hour().minute()))
            Text(event.title).bold()
        }
        .font(.caption)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(4)
        .frame(height: height, alignment: .top)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(.teal).opacity(0.5)
        )
        .padding(.trailing, 30)
        .offset(x: 30, y: offset + 24)

    }
    
}


func dateFrom(_ day: Int, _ month: Int, _ year: Int, _ hour: Int = 0, _ minute: Int = 0) -> Date {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute)
    return calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? .now
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Match your event time with your `ForEach` time you can use `DateComponents`.

```
///Hours in a day - First ForEach
let hourlyComponents: [DateComponents] = (0...23).map { hour in
    DateComponents(hour: hour)
}
```

Then you can "group" your events by the hour.

```
var eventsByHour: [DateComponents: [Event]]{
    Dictionary(grouping: events) { element in
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: element.startDate)
    }
}
```

Now to find the events per each hour you can use.

```
ForEach(eventsByHour[hourlyComponent, default: []], id:\.id){ event in
```

To size it you can figure out the `elapsedHours` and use something like

```
.frame(height: height * event.elapsedHours)
```

If the event is 1.5 hours the size will be 1.5 times the height.

As for adjusting for the minutes such as 11:15 you can get the hour equivalent of the minutes and turn it into hours and then offset.

```
.offset(y: height * event.startPosition)
```

With 15 minutes being 0.25 of an hour.

I suggest using `Calendar` and `Measurement` to do all the math.

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: max(startDate, midnightStart), to: min(endDate, midnightEnd))
let minToHour = Measurement(value: Double(components.minute ?? 0), unit: UnitDuration.minutes).converted(to: .hours)
let elapsedHours = Double(components.hour ?? 0) + minToHour.value
```