# Calendar MonthView Spaning events bar across multiple days

Tags: ios, swiftui, calendar, grid

I am creating monthly calendar view in swiftUI using below code which draw a grid and events inside of each date cell. When an event is for multiple days, it repeats in each cell. However my requirements is to show event as long bar if event is for multiple days. My question is how can achieve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKarr.jpg)

Below is my code

```
    var calendarGrid: some View
    {
        
        VStack(spacing: 1)
        {
            let daysInMonth = THCalendarHelper().daysInMonth(dateHolder.date)
            let firstDayOfMonth = THCalendarHelper().firstOfMonth(dateHolder.date)
            let startingSpaces = THCalendarHelper().weekDay(firstDayOfMonth)
            let prevMonth = THCalendarHelper().minusMonth(dateHolder.date)
            let daysInPrevMonth = THCalendarHelper().daysInMonth(prevMonth)
            
            let startDate = THCalendarHelper().minusDate(firstDayOfMonth, by: startingSpaces)
            
            ForEach(0..<6)
            {
                
                row in
                
                HStack(alignment:.top, spacing: 1)
                {
                    ForEach(1..<8)
                    {
                        column in
                        
                        VStack{
                            
                            let count = column + (row * 7)
                            let date = THCalendarHelper().plusDate(startDate, by: count - 1)
                            let startOfDay = currentCalendar.startOfDay(for: date)
                        
                            let dateRangeEvents = vm.details.filter({startOfDay.isInRange(startDate: $0.start, and: $0.end)})
                        
                            THCalendarCell(count: count, startingSpaces:startingSpaces, daysInMonth: daysInMonth, daysInPrevMonth: daysInPrevMonth, date:date, events:dateRangeEvents)
                                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .environmentObject(dateHolder)
                        }
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        
                        Divider()
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                Divider()
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
```

CalendarCell

```
VStack(spacing:3){
            VStack{
                Text(monthStruct().day())
                    .font(.roboto(size: .small, fontStroke: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(textColor(type: monthStruct().monthType))
                    .padding([.vertical], 5)
                
                ForEach(events){ event in
                    VStack{
                        HStack{
                            Text(event.title)
                                .eventTag(bg: Color.clear, fr: .white)
                        }
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Text(String("\(event.filledCount ?? 0) / \(event.maxPeople ?? 0)"))
                                .font(.poppins(size: .verysmall, fontStroke: .medium))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(3)
                                .background(.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                                .padding([.bottom], 5)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color(hex: event.backgroundColor))
                }
                
                Spacer() //// to align top date event
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqY14.jpg)

i tried by nested loop but doesn't expand the event in multiple dates

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213682/create-a-daily-timeline-calendar-in-swiftui/76258394#76258394) is for hourly it is a similar concept

Comment: i tried by finding start position and width of the bar (from event start and end date). If using VStack under rows loop then each event comes down to above one resulting a lot of empty space horizontally.